# how to Insert SQL query from previous database table value to pass to another database table with dynamic value in Katalon

Tags: katalon

Hi any one can help me on this issue which i have problem insert a dynamic value which is from previous database table value to pass to another table in Katalon.

Please find my information below:-

1. This screenshot is ab.dbo.DOCUMENT table which DOCUMENT_ID is auto populate with value
   which mean it will appear random number by itself.

[image]

2. Another screenshot is bc.dbo.DOCUMENT_IC table which i need to manually key in DOCUMENT_ID in
   the value base on on what it is given from ab.dbo.DOCUMENT table DOCUMENT_ID.
   Attached of a screenshot for bc.dbo.DOCUMENT_IC

[image]

3. In Katalon i am using a keyword to connect my database, insert query and close
   connection. I am aware of this step and able to connect to database with katalon. But i
   am not very sure how to pass a dynamic value from ab.dbo.DOCUMENT table DOCUMENT_ID which
   it can randomly appear a number value to bc.dbo.DOCUMENT_IC table DOCUMENT_ID which i need to
   manually key in a value base on the value given.

   Below is my Katalon script:-

[image]

Hopefully someone can help me on this
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a table with an auto incrementing ID in one table and I need that value elsewhere I would typically write sql like this :

insert into firsttable (Document_Type) values ('PDF');

insert into secondtable (Document_ID, App_ref_Num) values (@@Identity, 'somenumber')

In the databases I have worked with @@Identity will give you the integer or id of the last inserted row. If you can't run multiple statements most connection libraries will have something like a $conn->insert_id that will do the same thing as running select @@identity.

Comment: Sorry John i don't understand how is the multiple statement works. Do you have any guide? what is the file i need to input into the libraries?

Comment: If you wanted to return a value from the database, how would you do it in Katalon?